# how to display error message next to textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. So I had a doubt  for the following function, how to display the error message next to text box? right now it is showing a alert message, but I need to change the alert message and need to  display it  next to textbox?

```
function AllowLock(){
    if (!locker.lock.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && locker.lock.value !="") {
        locker.lock.value="";
        alert("Please Enter only valid lock");
    }
    if(locker.lock.value.length > 5)
        alert("max length exceeded");
    } 
}
```

Comment: U should create a custom alert that u then can position with CSS next to your textbox. An approach is have a hidden div in your HTML and make it visible when the errors occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have any container for that message, so you can create element and then append your message to that, 
something like this, with jquery

```
 <input type="text" id="kuku"></input>

$('#kuku').after('<div></div>').html("your message");
```

Comment: can u able to do it with table?

Comment: what do you mean with table ?

Comment: u mean append table instead of div ? if yes, actually u can append any element with after function. u mean this $('#kuku').after('<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>').html("your message");  ?

Comment: @ashokkumar can put more clear html code please, i cant understand what u did, in jsFiddle, put your html code in html part, css in css part, and don't forget to format it

Comment: yeah i got footer at the bottom,but how to align that header to the top using table tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a span element next to your textbox

```
<input type="text" /><span id="msg"></span>
```

and put your message.

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "your message";
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on anna's answer here is a example usage.. this code is the called on the on click of my 'continue' button.
Removes all existing error messages at start so they dont stack up etc.

```
<input id="userZip" type="number">
<input id="userName" type="text">
$('.errorText').remove();
userZip.style.border = "1px solid black";
userName.style.border = "1px solid black";
if(userName.value.length >= 3){
  if(userZip.value.length == 5){
    //success
    loginPanel.style.display = "none";
    location.href='#appNavigation/'+'mapNav';
  } else {
    userZip.style.border = "1px solid red";
    $('#userZip').after('<div class="errorText">Zipcode required. 5 numbers</div>');
  }
} else {
  userName.style.border = "1px solid red";
  $('#userName').after('<div class="errorText">Username required. 3 or more characters</div>');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).